# Beanstalk in a centralized server, how to avoid duplicate work for a worker?

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I have a server that runs Beanstalk, and some independent servers that runs the workers, in PHP, with Pheanstalk.

From the moment a worker A get a job :

```
$job = $pheanstalk->watch('tube')
    ->ignore('default')
    ->reserve();

$data = json_decode($job->getData(), true);
```

And the moment it delete the job (`$pheanstalk->delete($job);`), it could happens a few ten seconds.

Does Beanstalk know the job is being processed and no other worker will have it, or will I have a concurrency problem? (two worker taking the same job).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeanstalkD knows the job that is being processed, so it won't serve the job to another worker while it is processing it.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I want to hear, but do you have link to confirm your answer?

Comment: When a job has been reserved it's status changed to _reserved_.
"reserve" command serve only jobs with _ready_ status.
https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)